# Error when uploading applet on Java Card

Tags: javacard, apdu

Till yesterday I could upload my Java Card applets on card without any problem.But today I get a strange error.

[image: image below]

It seems to me that GpShell doesn't found the applet manager and throw me the`6d00` status error.This seems to me strange because  I haven't changed the instalation/deletion/listing scripts since begin.Any operation I try to do gives me the below status error.

Comment: I had a card which behaved exactly the same way (it was G&D Mobile Security Card which gave `6D00` even for SELECT. The card was already shipped in this state /so I can't tell what might have caused this/. G&D refused support as this product was discontinued). Yours is probably Gemalto one...try asking them what has happened...Good luck!

Comment: Didn't you tried to upload and install a manipulated cap file on the card? Maybe you activated a seld-destruct mechanism?

Comment: @EbraHim I uploaded the same applet on the card for on month.I guess the card has reached the maximum number of writes

Comment: @vlp or I thinn I will buy another card.I am working on a final year project and I don't have so mutch time to waste

Comment: Can you please send `00 a4 04 00 00` to card and add the response to your question?

Comment: @EbraHim I don't have acces to the card right now but I try to send an delete/install/list script but failed.I try with and without securing the channel ( open -sc ) .I also try to send and apdu with data and failed with the same error message.I try to skip over the selection of the applet manager and failed at the send method .I will post the resut as soon as I have acces to the card